# Running PHP7.4 FPM on Ubuntu. Forgot to install PHP7.2-curl. Wondering if I will need to bring down all the other websites for the change

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, curl

So I run a server with about 7 websites.

Just wondering if adding a module I will have to bring down the php-fpm and thus reboot the nginx process or adding a module.

Nginx Ubuntu 20.04 php 7.4 mariadb

When running

> sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl

I also get

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php7.4-curl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd php7.4-json php7.4-mysql php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline php7.4-zip
```

but php mysqli  and json and zip and readline are already installed with php 7.4.33 which are the latest versions...

### Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When restarting php-fpm, it is all or nothing. Unfortunately there is no way to restart an individual site pool.

Comment: any thoughts as to why it is upgrading already installed packages?